# anaconda packages not showing up in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I installed a new anaconda env in the command line, then connect the python binary in Pycharm:

/Users//anaconda3/envs/

However. None of the additional packages I installed are in pycharm

Comment: Actually my solution isn't complete... although the packages are showing up now in the Project Interpreter screen, I'm still getting import errors when I debug with that interpreter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Pycharm -> Preferences -> Project Interpreter. At the bottom left there is a plus sign, minus sign, and green circle that says "Use Conda Package manager". uncheck that

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was solved by setting the path to Conda at the project creation time (creating with with new Conda environment) to the "(Anaconda directory)\Scripts\conda.exe".

It looks like the path is then set globally for all projects. The file that stores that setting is "(User folder)(PyCharm Folder)\config\options\conda-packages.xml". Changing the PREFERRED_CONDA_PATH to the correct one in that file resolved the issue.